# Do I have to call a release function using a ComPtr?

Tags: c++, directx

I'm using a smart pointer or a ComPtr. I'm using it with my directX application and I haven't seen other people call the release function in their code using the ComPtr. So does the smart pointer release the data that the smart pointer is referring to or do I need to do it manually? I don't know if this makes since so tell me if it doesn't and I will respond with better detail.

Comment: ComPtr: "Creates a smart pointer type that represents the interface specified by the template parameter. ComPtr automatically maintains a reference count for the underlying interface pointer and releases the interface when the reference count goes to zero." source MSDN: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/br244983.aspx

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should never call `AddRef` or `Release` on a `ComPtr`, and by default you can't. You have to use hacky patterns like `comPtr.Get()->Release` to do it, and you are mostly like going to cause problems.

The purpose of `Microsoft::WRL::ComPtr` is to make COM pointer cleanup automatic, both in normal code and when handling C++ exceptions. Making a copy of a ComPtr to another ComPtr automatically increase the ref-count, and each time a ComPtr variable goes out of scope it automatically decreases the ref-count. This greatly simplifies error-handling and cleanup which is why the code you are looking at isn't awash in calls to `Release`.

There are special methods `Attach` and `Detach` for 'transferring ownership' so that the ref-count is not changed, but they are for special use cases. There are also some tricks you can do with `Swap` as well that are very useful for robust coding.

If you want to explicitly 'release' a ComPtr variable, you can assign null to it or better yet use `Reset`.

Like with all [smart-pointers](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh279674.aspx) you should think about the lifetime of your pointer to decide how to use it. If a function or class is going to 'own' the object pointed to, then use of a smart-pointer is the right way to do it. If the function is just going to work with the object and then return without any change in lifetime, the function should take a raw pointer instead with you using the `Get` method on the ComPtr when calling it. Otherwise your program wastes a lot of time needlessly increasing and decreasing the ref-count when the ownership of the object was not actually in question.

> Another option is to pass the smart-pointer parameter as `const ComPtr&` which avoids the ref-count cycling, but it has the side-effect of forcing the caller to use `ComPtr` when the raw pointer is more agnostic to the caller's object lifetime policy and therefore more flexible.

I've got a write-up of how to use `ComPtr` on the [DirectX Tool Kit wiki](https://github.com/Microsoft/DirectXTK/wiki/ComPtr). You can also see [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/br244983.aspx).

> For non-COM objects, `std::unique_ptr` is a great option. You can also use `std::shared_ptr` and `std::weak_ptr` but there are a lot of performance implications and edge-cases to worry about in the shared case, so sticking to `ComPtr` for COM and `std::unique_ptr` for heap-allocated objects with a single-owner is best practice.

Answer (score 2):

You should not normally need to call `AddRef` or `Release` through the smart pointer - the entire point of `ComPtr` is that it calls those for you.

You might still need to call them if you're converting a smart pointer to a "manually managed" (normal) pointer.